# Facebook Like, controlling the image presented on facebook timeline

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using the  header element the Like image presented on facebook timeline can be controlled.

I have a single page app with multiple like buttons, each should be associated with a different image.

**How can I have a specific image associated with each of the Like buttons on my page?**

Answer (score 0):

if every like button refer a webpage under your control you can add this meta tag in every page.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="url to image" />
```

refer [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects) for documentation

Comment: I have a single page with multiple like buttons ( Single page app ), I need each like button to refer to a different image

Answer (score 0):

Even if the app itself is single-page, the Open Graph system uses URLs as unique identifiers. Consider creating dummy pages that use the proper metadata for each object and have your like buttons configured with those URLs.